# Change serializers on per-object basis within one ViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project with some social features and need to make it so that a User can see all details of his profile, but only public parts of others' profiles.
Is there a way to do this within one ViewSet?

Here's a sample of my model:

```
class Profile(TimestampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, default='M',
        choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')))

    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

For this model, I'd like the birthday, for example, to stay private.
In the actual model there's about a dozen such fields.

My serializers:

```
class FullProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile


class BasicProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = read_only_fields = ('nickname', 'sex', 'birthday')
```

A custom permission I wrote:

```
class ProfilePermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Handles permissions for users.  The basic rules are

    - owner and staff may do anything
    - others can only GET
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        else:
            return request.user == obj.user or request.user.is_staff
```

And my viewset:

```
class RUViewSet(
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
        mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """ViewSet with update/retrieve powers."""


class ProfileViewSet(RUViewSet):
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, ProfilePermission)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_staff:
            return FullProfileSerializer
        return BasicProfileSerializer
```

What I'd like is for `request.user`'s own profile in the queryset to be serialized using `FullProfileSerializer`, but the rest using `BasicProfileSerializer`.
Is this at all possible using DRF's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override the `retrieve()` and `list` methods in our `ProfileViewSet` to return different serialized data depending on the user being viewed.

In the `list` method, we serialize all the user instances excluding the current user with the serializer returned from `get_serializer_class()` method. Then we serialize the current user profile information using the `FullProfileSerializer` explicitly and add this serialized data to the data returned before.

In the `retrieve` method, we set a `accessed_profile` attribute on the view to know about the user the view is displaying. Then, we will use this attribute to decide the serializer in the `get_serializer_class()` method.

```
class ProfileViewSet(RUViewSet):
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, ProfilePermission)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).exclude(user=self.request.user)
        page = self.paginate_queryset(instance)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)
        other_profiles_data = serializer.data # serialized profiles data for users other than current user
        current_user_profile = <get_the_current_user_profile_object>
        current_user_profile_data = FullProfileSerializer(current_user_profile).data
        all_profiles_data = other_profiles_data.append(current_user_profile_data)
        return Response(all_profiles_data)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.accessed_profile = self.get_object() # set this as on attribute on the view
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.accessed_profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
        if current_user.is_staff or (self.action=='retrieve' and self.accessed_profile.user==current_user):
            return FullProfileSerializer    
        return BasicProfileSerializer
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way to do it without delving into serializer innards, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hack together the solution that provides the wanted behaviour for the `detail` view:

```
class ProfileViewSet(RUViewSet):
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, ProfilePermission)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_staff:
            return FullProfileSerializer
        return BasicProfileSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):

        if hasattr(instance, 'user'):
            user = self.request.user

            if instance.user == user or user.is_staff:
                kwargs['instance'] = instance
                kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
                return FullProfileSerializer(*args, **kwargs)

        return super(ProfileViewSet, self).get_serializer(
            instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

This doesn't work for the `list` view, however, as that one provides the `get_serializer` method with a Django `Queryset` object in place of an actual instance.
I'd still like to see this behaviour in a `list` view, i.e. when serializing many objects, so if anyone knows a more elegant way to do this that also covers the `list` view I'd much appreciate your answer.